# ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'filter not found'}

Tags: etherscan, web3.py

I am tring to get all holders of a particular contract through web3.py library.For RPC I am using infura.

the code is:

```
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=address,abi=abi)
name = contract.functions.name().call()
print(name)


def holdersEvent(_fromBlock, _toBlock):
    try:
        transferEvents = contract.events.Transfer.createFilter(fromBlock=_fromBlock, toBlock=_toBlock)
        for i in range(len(transferEvents.get_all_entries())):
            addressTo = transferEvents.get_all_entries()[i].args.to
            print(addressTo)
    except error:
        #holdersEvent(_fromBlock, _toBlock)
        print(_fromBlock," ",_toBlock)


latest = web3.eth.blockNumber
firstBlock = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash).blockNumber
totalResult = latest - firstBlock

initial = firstBlock
if totalResult >2000:
    while totalResult>=2000:
        fromBlock = initial
        toBlock = initial +2000
        holdersEvent(fromBlock,toBlock)
        totalResult = totalResult -2000
        initial = toBlock
    if totalResult != 0:
        fromBlock = initial
        toBlock = initial + totalResult
        holdersEvent(fromBlock,toBlock)
else:
    holdersEvent(firstBlock,latest)
```

under this I am facing the error as

```
ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'filter not found'}
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Most public nodes do not support filters, pending blocks, etc.

To access those features for JSON-RPC you need to run your own node.

Comment: I found the solution I have to use WebSocket rather than HTTP